# Apache HTTP Client POST throws 500

Tags: java, apache, rest, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to execute a POST request by using apache http client

http://hc.apache.org/

here is the code snippet

```
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xav.com/asd");

        JSONObject jon = new JSONObject();
        jon.put("param", "val");
        jon.put("param2", "val2");

        String json = jon.toString();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        client.close();
```

but i get a 500 error. I can execute the same POST request using the swagger UI that exists. I am assuming that something is wrong in the construction of my request and that the parameters are not being passed properly to the back end.

Have i created the POST request correctly? Is there a way to get the actual URL, after the parameters have been added?

Answer (score 0):

It just works, and it returns 404, not 500.

```
...
<title>Error 404 Document Not Found on http://xav.com/asd</title>
...
```

404 is actually the right response for http://xav.com/asd in your example.

Here is the program:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ApacheHttpClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xav.com/asd");

        JSONObject jon = new JSONObject();
        jon.put("param", "val");
        jon.put("param2", "val2");

        String json = jon.toString();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        client.close();
    }
}
```

And below are the libraries I use:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20170516</version>
</dependency>
```

If you try another public web service, http://www.posttestserver.com/, you will get HTTP status 200:

```
Successfully dumped 0 post variables.
View it at http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2017/05/25/22.39.57585465710
No Post body.
```

And below is the program:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ApacheHttpClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");

        JSONObject jon = new JSONObject();
        jon.put("param", "val");
        jon.put("param2", "val2");

        // Returns the original request URI. Please note URI remains 
        // unchanged in the course of request execution and is not 
        // updated if the request is redirected to another location.
        System.out.println("URI: " + httpPost.getURI());
        // URI: http://posttestserver.com/post.php            

        String json = jon.toString();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, note that i am using a junk URL for the purpose of this post. so you will get 404 because the website does not exist

Comment: In my answer, I also tried: http://posttestserver.com/post.php, and it gets 200. My suggestion is, double-check the libraries you are using.

Comment: ok, is there a way to see the fully formed url that is created by the http client?

Comment: Not sure if `httpPost.getURI()` is what you need. (See the second example in the updated answer)